# Given a circle with radius $10$. There are $10$ points $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_9, A_{10}$ on the circle with equal gap. Find $A_{10}A_3-A_1A_2$.

Tags: geometry

> Given a circle with radius $10$. There are $10$ points $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_9, A_{10}$ on the circle with equal gap. Find $A_{10}A_3-A_1A_2$.

I have tried to solve it by joining every segment to the centre and tried using calculating areas and angles. But I have failed. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Are the points placed along the circle in the order in which they are numbered? And is the gap between $A_{10}$ and $A_1$ the same as the other gaps?

Comment: Do you mean that the points belong to a **regular** decagon (regular polygon with 10 vertices (or 10 sides)) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Rotating the segments to be horizontal shows that $A_iA_j=20\sin\left(\tfrac{j-i}{10}\pi\right)$.

Comment: 10 is the radius, not the diameter.

Comment: @JeanMarie You are right, I have corrected the hint.